# Chat flagging system and old messages

Tags: feature-request, chat

There seems to a flaw (imho) in the chat room flagging system. What I've seen happen multiple times is:

- Someone says something that is borderline flaggable.
- No-one takes offence during the time.
- Someone else sees the message by going through the chat archive and flags it.
- Hordes more people from other rooms flag the message sometimes hours, sometimes longer after it was written.

In some cases the message that has been flagged is a private joke between two friends. When the message is flagged hours later, neither of them have been around to say that the flag is invalid.

I don't believe the flagging system is meant to be used for old messages; instead it is for stuff where someone is currently being abusive.

Could the flag the system should be changed so that either:

i) it is not possible to flag messages that are either x hours old, or have had y messages posted after them.

ii) Instead of alerting every 10k user in real-time, those flags on old messages should only be shown to 10k'ers in the room, or room owners.

Either of those would prevent the flagging of old messages, and the stampede effect which currently disrupts the chat rooms every now and again.

Alternatively, we could just disable the flag system - that ignore button is there for a reason...

Comment: Alternatively to ii) we also could make flag invalidations from people in this room count doubly. [As these know context.]

Comment: Meh, don't change it. I like to show up in places uninvited, post one or two mind-boggling messages, leave and then being pinged for hours by confused regulars of that room...

Comment: You can flag old things everywhere else on the site.  How is this any different?

Comment: Also, ignore doesn't work in the transcript, and everyone has to do it individually.  So people reading stuff later would see offensive things that everyone else didn't deal with because they were ignoring it.

Comment: "You can flag old things everywhere else on the site. How is this any different?" People see questions and answers on the first page they land on in the site. Very few people see the chat transcript. Also - flagging content on the rest of the site sends it to a mod who can remove it. Flagging chat messages doesn't - instead it just gets the person who said it a timeout from chatting.

Comment: This would be bad for chat rooms with lower usage as it is possible for a message to sit for a while without being noticed.

Comment: @JoeW I think if it's sat for 12 hours without being flagged, then flagging it is unlikely to be useful. Instead it would be appropriate for the room owner or a mod to do something.

Comment: If it is an inside joke meant for two people then don't use a public chat room and you won't run the risk ;)

Comment: I sometimes read chat messages from earlier in the day, or even a couple of days ago, in fairly quiet rooms such as Japanese's chat room.

Comment: *"In some cases the message that has been flagged is a private joke between two friends."* That's not a very good excuse for saying something that offended someone else enough to flag it. Unless you're concerned that someone is intentionally trying to find flaggable stuff, I don't see how this could be a problem.

Comment: Oh look, another requests about flags. [tag:status-declined-as-usual-try-again-in-two-years-perhaps-cheers]

Comment: A joke cannot be considered private if said in a public forum.

Comment: @bwoebi: "we also could make flag invalidations from people in this room count doubly".  Let's not: Some rooms make a habit of permitting fowl language; the room's users aggressively invalidate any flags that are raised.  If anything, make the votes of those in the room count _less_.

Comment: @WayneConrad Fowl language is for the birds.

Comment: @BillWoodger Heh.  I see what you did there.  And what I did as well. :D

Comment: @WayneConrad In the case that goes bad, there's always still the possibility of directly notifying moderators. But often it's just regulars saying something everyone from outside would consider as possibly offensive. They just see one message then, but only few look context up. — hence if people in that room invalidate the flags, they do it because they _know_ that no offense was meant, what other 10k people won't know [and thus validate the flag].

Comment: Entire flagging system is dumb and broken and completely incompatible with the format and we've been saying that for years and you can guess how much it changed.